# Lowest free value in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I already searched but I always find LEAST and GREATEST as hints. I want to have the next ascending number in a row that's not used. Like the following:

```
entries
1
2
3
5
6
7
```

If every of the numbers is for one row in my table I want the number 4 as a result and in the following example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want the number 7 as a result. Is there any possiblity to accomplish this in an SQL statement?

Best,
Robin

Comment: Imagine you have items you sell and every item gets a number. The first you sell gets the number 1 and the second the number 2. Now someone buys number 3 and now number is being returned. For reasons now number 2 is free again and needs to be sold too. It's a bit difficult, but in this case I need this. Of course I could also use php to accomplish that, but I thought it might be that there also would be a solution in mysql.

Comment: But who cares if it's number 4 or number 7? Who cares if there are gaps? And, what if no. 1 is missing? This kind of question usually points to a profound misunderstanding of the importance of data integrity.

Comment: You need not to use database for this task

Comment: Are you just looking for some smart autoincrement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query assumes that the number 1 is in your table

```
select min(number) + 1 from entries e1
where not exists (
    select 1 from entries e2
    where e2.number = e1.number + 1
)
```

If you want all missing numbers (where gaps are no larger than 1) instead of the smallest one, then remove `min()`

Comment: "If you want all missing numbers [where gaps are no larger than 1]..."

Comment: i suppose you could see it that way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It think the solution is to do a self-join with the next value, and extract the first lowest result. Example:

Table: `values`, with column `value`

```
SELECT v1.value
FROM values v1
LEFT JOIN values v2 ON v1.value = (v2.value + 1)
WHERE v2.value IS NULL
ORDER BY v1.value ASC
LIMIT 1
```